# Asp.Net-5 Class Library (Package) Test Inject IOptions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have created a new proyect: Class Library (Package) to test my repositories,
because i need test a DataRepository tier that i am consuming from asp.net vnext.

I want use DI like asp.net vnext but i can't create an instance from IServiceCollection and inject IOptions.

i have tried with

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddTransient<ISampleRepository, SampleRepository>()
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

The Ctor of the SampleRepository is

```
public SampleRepository(IOptions<Settings> settings)
```

But i am having the following error message:

Result Message: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel.IOptions`1[Repository.Sample.Settings]'
while attempting to activate 'Repository.Sample.SampleRepository'.

Comment: Thanks so much @KiranChalla for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the `OptionsManager` service to resolve types like `IOptions<>`

`.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IOptions<>), typeof(OptionsManager<>)));`

Comment: Great! Excelent!

services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IOptions<Settings>), typeof(OptionsManager<Settings>)));

Comment: @MarceloOliveto: do not register a service specifically for `Settings` alone as the one I pasted above is generic and can apply to other types too.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to populate and register that `Repository.Sample.Settings` object:

```cs
serviceProvider.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));
```

or;

```
serviceProvider.Configure<Settings>(options =>
{
    options.MyField1 = Configuration["Settings:MyField1"];
    options.MyField2 = Configuration["Settings:MyField2"];
});
```